# Assistance needed - Map does not load properly in JQuery UI Tabs - NOT A DUPLICATE

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, google-maps-api-3, jquery-ui-tabs

**None of the "Answers" from the other post resolve my issue.  Please Read My Post and Attempt to guide me in the right direction**

***EDIT - EDIT - EDIT***

***I have updated the java script to include the recommended function***

***I have included the HTML here for those who do not like jsfiddle***

I have read tons of questions and answers here and I cannot get my Google Map to load properly in the JQueryUI Tab that it is called in.

I understand that the map must load first but I am not able to get the Tab to load then return to the Home tab.  I have tried the Off Left Technique to no avail.

I need help.  A fresh set of Eyes would be extremely Helpful.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am extremely far behind on this project.

Please review the jsfiddle referenced below, and tell me where I am going wrong.  I am at my whits end and really could use a little intervention with this.  One of you Java/jqueryui Guru's surely can see where i am going wrong with a quick little peak.

The issue is on the ***LOCATION*** Tab

The jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/hughesjoseph/hNKPY/

The test site http://l2technotes.dyndns.org

Loads correctly if you go to address/#tabs-4

**Complete Java Script**

```
        (function (mapDemo, $, undefined) {
    mapDemo.Directions = (function () {
        function _Directions() {
            var map,
            directionsService, directionsDisplay,
            autoSrc, autoDest, pinA, pinB,

            markerA = new google.maps.MarkerImage('images/car.png'),
                markerB = new google.maps.MarkerImage('images/gmaplogo.png'),

            // Caching the Selectors
                $Selectors = {
                    mapCanvas: jQuery('#mapCanvas')[0],
                    dirPanel: jQuery('#directionsPanel'),
                    dirInputs: jQuery('.directionInputs'),
                    dirSrc: jQuery('#dirSource'),
                    dirDst: jQuery('#dirDestination'),
                    getDirBtn: jQuery('#getDirections'),
                    dirSteps: jQuery('#directionSteps'),
                    paneToggle: jQuery('#paneToggle'),
                    useGPSBtn: jQuery('#useGPS'),
                    paneResetBtn: jQuery('#paneReset')
                },

                autoCompleteSetup = function () {
                    autoSrc = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($Selectors.dirSrc[0]);
                    autoDest = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($Selectors.dirDst[0]);
                }, // autoCompleteSetup Ends

                directionsSetup = function () {
                    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
                    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
                        suppressMarkers: true
                    });

                    directionsDisplay.setPanel($Selectors.dirSteps[0]);
                }, // direstionsSetup Ends

                trafficSetup = function () {
                    // Creating a Custom Control and appending it to the map
                    var controlDiv = document.createElement('div'),
                        controlUI = document.createElement('div'),
                        trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();

                    jQuery(controlDiv).addClass('gmap-control-container').addClass('gmnoprint');
                    jQuery(controlUI).text('Traffic').addClass('gmap-control');
                    jQuery(controlDiv).append(controlUI);

                    // Traffic Btn Click Event
                    google.maps.event.addDomListener(controlUI, 'click', function () {
                        if (typeof trafficLayer.getMap() == 'undefined' || trafficLayer.getMap() === null) {
                            jQuery(controlUI).addClass('gmap-control-active');
                            trafficLayer.setMap(map);
                        } else {
                            trafficLayer.setMap(null);
                            jQuery(controlUI).removeClass('gmap-control-active');
                        }
                    });
                    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(controlDiv);
                }, // trafficSetup Ends

                mapSetup = function () {
                    map = new google.maps.Map($Selectors.mapCanvas, {
                        zoom: 16,
                        center: new google.maps.LatLng(32.565243, -97.130531),

                        mapTypeControl: true,
                        mapTypeControlOptions: {
                            style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DEFAULT,
                            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
                        },

                        panControl: true,
                        panControlOptions: {
                            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP
                        },

                        zoomControl: true,
                        zoomControlOptions: {
                            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
                            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP
                        },

                        scaleControl: true,
                        streetViewControl: true,
                        overviewMapControl: true,

                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    });

                    var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(32.565243, -97.130531),
                        map: map,
                        icon: markerB
                    });

                    autoCompleteSetup();
                    directionsSetup();
                    trafficSetup();
                }, // mapSetup Ends 

                directionsRender = function (source, destination) {
                    $Selectors.dirSteps.find('.msg').hide();
                    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

                    var request = {
                        origin: source,
                        destination: destination,
                        provideRouteAlternatives: false,
                        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
                    };

                    directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
                        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

                            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

                            var _route = response.routes[0].legs[0];

                            pinA = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position: _route.start_location,
                                map: map,
                                icon: markerA
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }, // directionsRender Ends

                fetchAddress = function (p) {
                    var Position = new google.maps.LatLng(p.coords.latitude, p.coords.longitude),
                        Locater = new google.maps.Geocoder();

                    Locater.geocode({
                        'latLng': Position
                    }, function (results, status) {
                        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                            var _r = results[0];
                            $Selectors.dirSrc.val(_r.formatted_address);
                        }
                    });
                }, // fetchAddress Ends

                invokeEvents = function () {
                    // Get Directions
                    $Selectors.getDirBtn.on('click', function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        var src = $Selectors.dirSrc.val(),
                            dst = $Selectors.dirDst.val();

                        directionsRender(src, dst);
                    });

                    // Reset Btn
                    $Selectors.paneResetBtn.on('click', function (e) {
                        $Selectors.dirSteps.html('');
                        $Selectors.dirSrc.val('');
                        $Selectors.dirDst.val('');

                        if (pinA) pinA.setMap(null);
                        if (pinB) pinB.setMap(null);

                        directionsDisplay.setMap(null);
                    });

                    // Toggle Btn
                    $Selectors.paneToggle.toggle(function (e) {
                        $Selectors.dirPanel.animate({
                            'left': '-=305px'
                        });
                        jQuery(this).html('&gt;');
                    }, function () {
                        $Selectors.dirPanel.animate({
                            'left': '+=305px'
                        });
                        jQuery(this).html('&lt;');
                    });

                    // Use My Location / Geo Location Btn
                    $Selectors.useGPSBtn.on('click', function (e) {
                        if (navigator.geolocation) {
                            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                                fetchAddress(position);
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }, //invokeEvents Ends 

                _init = function () {
                    mapSetup();
                    invokeEvents();
                }; // _init Ends

            this.init = function () {
                _init();
                return this; // Refers to: mapDemo.Directions
            };
            return this.init(); // Refers to: mapDemo.Directions.init()
        } // _Directions Ends
        return new _Directions(); // Creating a new object of _Directions rather than a function
    } ()); // mapDemo.Directions Ends
})(window.mapDemo = window.mapDemo || {}, jQuery);
var mapFirstClick = false;
$("#maptab").click(function () {
    mapFirstClick || setTimeout(function () {
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
        mapFirstClick = true;
        map.setCenter(32.565243, -97.130531);
    }, 250);
});
function PrintElem(elem) {
    Popup($(elem).html());
}
function Popup(data) {
    var mywindow = window.open('', 'my div', 'height=600,width=800');
    mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Driving Directions to Electrolysis by Bridgett</title>');
    mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
    mywindow.document.write(data);
    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
    mywindow.print();
    mywindow.close();
    return true;
}
$(function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
});
$(function () {
    $("#accordion").accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        active: false,
        heightStyle: "content"
    });
});
```

**Pertinent HTML**

```
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Electrolysis by Bridgett</title>
        <!-- Favorite Icon -->
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/beLogoColor3D.png" />
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>

    <body onload: "#maptab";>
        <div id="tabs">
            <ul style="border:3px solid green">
                <li class="myMenu"><a href="#tabs-4" onclick="maptab"><img height="20px" src="images/map.png" alt="" class="img center" /> Location</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div id="tabs-4">
                <div class="myDirections" style="width:19%;">
                    <div>
                        <form>
                            <p>
                                <label class="mytxt">Driving From :</label>
                                <br />
                                <input type="text" value="" id="dirSource" style="width:98%;" />
                            </p>
                            <input type="hidden" value="1003 E. Broad St., 76063" id="dirDestination" />
                            <div class="mybutton"><a href="#getDirections" id="getDirections">Get Directions to<br />Electrolysis by Bridgett</a>
                            </div>
                            <center>
                                <input type="button" value="Print Directions" onclick="PrintElem('#directionSteps')" />
                            </center>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div id="directionSteps">
                        <center>
                            <p class="msg">Step by Step Directions Appear Here</p>
                        </center>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="myMap" style="width:78%;">
                    <div id="mapCanvas" style="width:100%;height:550px"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places" type="text/javascript"></script>
                <script src="js/jquery-1.9.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/sample.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this problem too:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

trigger this when tab is done fading in (default after 250 ms). This piece of code worked for me:

```
        var mapFirstClick = false;
        $("#tabMap").click(function() {
            mapFirstClick || setTimeout(function() {
                google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
                mapFirstClick = true;
                map.setCenter(latLng);
            }, 250);
        });
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have tried this unsuccessfully.  I am guessing that i am locating the Function or the Trigger in the wrong location.

Comment: Directed at Trott, Roman C, Shikiryu, Sindre Sorhus, Jayendra - This is not a duplicate question that has already been answered and this is a forum for people to get assistance with their issues.  Yes the answer below is similar but it is not the answer to my issue as of yet.  If you feel you must say something, make it useful and helpful even.

Comment: Got the Map to resize and recenter with the click event on the map but not on the Tab Click.  I get error "mapResize not defined" in the console.  Getting Closer.  Thanks to Ziamo for the assist.